# SQLIte Query, select everything that equals - Android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

```
// get friends
public Cursor getFriends(){
    Cursor c = dataBase.query(SqConstants.FRIENDS_TABLE_LOCAL, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    return c;
}
```

I have multiple tables in a SQLite database in my application for android.

I want to select everything from a column in a Friends Table (which holds integers) and select everything that equals that integer from a User Table (in the primary column which also is integer) and the get all the users which equals the numbers stored in the friends column.

It was some while I managed SQL databases but I think the query for a MySQL database would be something like:

```
SELECT * UsersID FROM TABLE Users EQUALS LOCAL_FRIENDS_ID FROM TABLE Friends
```

I might be wrong that it would look like this, but something like it.

What I want is to do this in android code, from a cursor get all the Users from the Users table which ID is equal to the FriendsID.

How do I change the above method to make it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use the `rawQuery`

```
Cursor c = dataBase.rawQuery(SELECT * UsersID FROM TABLE Users EQUALS LOCAL_FRIENDS_ID FROM TABLE Friends, null)
```

If you need to use a actual parameter for the `LOCAL_FRIENDS_ID`

```
string[1] args = new String[LOCAL_FRIENDS_ID.ToString()];
Cursor c = dataBase.rawQuery(SELECT * UsersID FROM TABLE Users EQUALS ? FROM TABLE Friends, args)
```